# How to make Hibernate ignore a property of a certain name?

Tags: scala, hibernate

I mapped a Scala class with Hibernate. The class contains a lazy val, so Scala automatically creates a class property called `bitmap$0` which is unfortunately mapped by Hibernate as well.

How can I prevent Hibernate from mapping this auto-generated property?

Comment: I haven't tested it but I assume marking your `lazy val` with Transient annotation should make it work:  `@transient lazy val foo = ???`.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding @Transient and/or @transient does not prevent the mapping of `bitmap$0`.  It only prevents the mapping of the lazy val property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.  I've set a custom `MetadataProvider` which fakes the `@Transient` annotation for the `bitmap$0` property.

Set the custom `MetadataProvider`:

```
configuration.getReflectionManager.asInstanceOf[JavaReflectionManager].setMetadataProvider(new JavaMetadataProvider {
    override def getAnnotationReader(annotatedElement: AnnotatedElement): AnnotationReader = {
        if (annotatedElement.toString.endsWith("bitmap$0")) {
            new TransientAnnotationReader(annotatedElement)
        } else {
            new JavaAnnotationReader(annotatedElement)
        }
    }
})
```

Involved classes:

```
class JavaAnnotationReader(val element: AnnotatedElement) extends AnnotationReader {
    override def getAnnotation[T <: Annotation](annotationType: Class[T]): T = element.getAnnotation(annotationType)

    override def isAnnotationPresent[T <: Annotation](annotationType: Class[T]): Boolean = element.isAnnotationPresent(annotationType)

    override def getAnnotations: Array[Annotation] = element.getAnnotations
}

class TransientAnnotationReader(val element: AnnotatedElement) extends AnnotationReader {
    override def getAnnotation[T <: Annotation](annotationType: Class[T]): T = element.getAnnotation(annotationType)

    override def isAnnotationPresent[T <: Annotation](annotationType: Class[T]): Boolean = annotationType == classOf[Transient]

    override def getAnnotations: Array[Annotation] = element.getAnnotations
}
```